# Cannot read property ' ' of null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to access some data from an API but when I do I get Cannot read property '5' of null

```
import React from "react";

function Card(props) {
  console.log(props.data[5].mission_name); //why is it that this doesn't work in my machine?
  console.log(props.data); //this works with my machine

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>test</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Card;
```

I initially set the data that I'm passing as null and then I update it once the data from the API loads so I'm thinking that might be part of the problem but I don't know how to get around it. I made a code sandbox for more context. And for reference I'm using the spacex api.

https://codesandbox.io/embed/gallant-mcnulty-lyied?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you log just `props`, what you see? Please, add it to the question since it is relevant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, you are initially setting the data value to null. When the Card initially renders, it'll try to index 5 on null and give you that error. Try something like

```
if (props.data) { // the first render (where data is null) will skip this block
  console.log(props.data[5].mission_name);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because sometimes your function is called when data is null.

So you have to check that before accessing an element of that data:

```
console.log(props.data && props.data[5].mission_name);
```